# CROSS JOIN in SQL (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to make a query like that

```
SELECT playerId, SUM(distance) as distance, sprint.sprint, SUM(calories) as calories,
    SUM(stepsRate) as steps, SUM(jump) as jump, deviceId as I
    FROM readings as re
    CROSS JOIN (select count(agg.maxSpeed) as sprint from(
            select max(r.distance) as maxSpeed, 
            CASE
                WHEN r.distance > 20 THEN @rownr
                ELSE @rownr := @rownr + 1
            END as flag
            from readings as r 
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownr := 0) AS dummy
            **where r.playerId = re.playerId**
            group by flag) as agg
            where agg.maxSpeed > 20) AS sprint
    GROUP BY playerId;
```

but the problem is I can't make Whare Statement in 
where r.playerId = re.playerId
I can't reach to playerId

My Reading Table Schema

```
Id int(11) AI PK 
deviceId varchar(50) 
playerId int(11) 
heartRate int(11) 
distance double 
calories double 
StepsRate double 
jump double 
sessionId int(11)
```

Some Sample Data

```
Id    | DeviceId | PlayerId | HeartRate | distance | calories
21711    AAAAA2     2016        148        38          10       
21721    AAAAA2     2016        126        33.5        13   
21731    AAAAA2     2016        111        33.5        6            
21741    AAAAA2     2016        192        33.5        22
```

Expected query result

```
PlayerId  | Distance | Sprint | Calories | Steps | DeviceId 
    1002       4993       49       6750       10     AAAAA1
    2016       2592       49       5775       10     AAAAA2
    2017       9994       49       7790       10     AAAAA3
    2018       5939       49       5350       10     AAAAA4
    2019       4794       49       6259       10     AAAAA5
```

The CROSS JOIN get the COUNT of Sprint but I can't pass the playerId to the WHERE statement in CROSS JOIN

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  A non-working query doesn't really express your intent.

Comment: How do you expect us to know what you want to do if all you give is a broken query????  First, describe what you want to achieve.  Second, give the table structure, desired output.  Learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask